# Use location variables in multiple actions?

Tags: ios, performance, gps

I'm using CLLocationManager to input the device's speed from GPS data.  Under the method "didUpdateToLocation", speed is defined as "currentLocation.speed" (code shown below).  However, if I want to use the value of "currentLocation.speed" in a button press action later in the code, it cannot find the variable.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {

    _speedOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.speed];
    _longitudeOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _latitudeOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
    }
```

How do I, in essence, "publicize a variable" so I can use it in multiple actions?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Use an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

If the actions are in the same class, just create a property and store the speed in it.  If they are in a different class, you could create a global variable and use that to store the speed.

Comment: Please don't use a global variable.

Comment: It's bad design and it doesn't scale.

Comment: Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Sure but it all depends on many other factors so it's difficult to offer concrete alternatives.

Comment: That's why I suggested it, because it works in a lot of situations and we don't have very many details.

Comment: I do understand that it can lead to messy code, though.